# LinqToTwitter rate limits for sending DMs

Tags: c#, linq, twitter, linq-to-twitter

After calling `TwitterContext.NewDirectMessageEventAsync`, the values for `RateLimitCurrent`, `RateLimitRemaining` and `RateLimitReset` are always `-1`.

From the Twitter docs, it appears the rate limit for [POSTing direct messages](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event) is 1000 per 24 hour window. Is there a reason why LinqToTwitter does not reveal the rate limit values?

I've looked at the results from `TwitterContext.Help` but I didn't find anything there for `direct_messages/events/new`.

Comment: The Twitter API itself does not return any hints in the HTTP headers for write / POST actions (these are per account and not on the API itself) so there is no reasonable way for LinqToTwitter or any other library to return you that information. It’s a Twitter limitation, nothing that LinqToTwitter can help with.

Comment: Thanks, @AndyPiper. Seems like the best approach is to catch a rate limit error and suspend outgoing DMs for an 24 hours (since I see no way of knowing when the current 24 hour limit began). Frustrating. Any better ideas?